# Polynomial with coefficients 'sufficiently close' to irreducible polynomial is irreducible

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, valuation-theory

In a paper I am reading, I think the following is implicitly used:

> Let $(K, v)$ be a valued field, $f$ an irreducible, monic polynomial over $K$. If $g$ is another monic polynomial over $K$ such that the values of all coefficients of $f-g$ are 'sufficiently high', then $g$ must also be irreducible.

Is this true in general? How would one argue this? It feels intuitive as being irreducible is somehow an open property, but I do not see how to make this formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on a famous lemma for complete valued fields ( I forgot the author). Here is a  version of it.

Say we have $K \subset L$ a Galois extension of complete valued fields, $v$ in $L$ with conjugates $v=v_1$, $v_2$, $\ldots$, $v_m$ and $w\in L$ so that
$$|w - v| < |w - v_i|$$ for all $i\ne 1$. Then $v \in K(w)$. Indeed, consider an element $\sigma \in Gal(L/K)$ so that $\sigma(w) = w$. Note that $\sigma$ invariates the norm, since $K$ is complete. Then $\sigma(v)$ must be $v$. Indeed, it cannot be $v_i$, since $|w-v| < |w- v_i|$.

Consequence: if $w \in K(v)$ is close enough to $v$ then $K(w) = K(v)$.

Let now $f$ the minimal polynomial of $f$. It has simple roots. By the implicit function theorem, if $g$ monic, with coefficients in $K$, is sufficiently close to $f$, the polynomial will have a root in $K(v)$ ( a complete field that contains the root $v$ of $f$).  Moreover, $w$ will be closer to $v$ than to the conjugates of $v$ ( in the normal closure of $K(v)$ ( for non-archimedean norm, the inequality $|w-v| < |v- v_i|$ for all $i \ne 1$ will do). We conclude that if $g$ sufficiently close to $f$, $g$ will have a root $w \in K(v)$, such that $K(w) = K(v)$. But then the degree of $w$ equals the degree of $v$. Therefore, $g$ has to be irreducible.

Comment: I think the name you are looking for is Krasner. :) Thanks for your answer, will take a look at it!

Comment: @Bib-lost: You are welcome., Yes, indeed, it is Krasner.

Comment: The implicit function theorem you speak of is, I assume, Hensel's Lemma?

Comment: @Bib-lost: I would think of it as the implicit function theorem. And it works in the analytic case. Hensel lemma in my understanding, is: if you have an approximate root for a given polynomial, then you have a root. But here you modify the polynomial in fact. OK, I guess you can use that too. But I prefer to think of it as implicit function theorem, since it's more general. Analytic functions are very useful.

Comment: Is this a thing in valuation theory? A quick google search did not find anything about an implicit function theorem for general valuations. Also, does a general valuation (with possibly non-Archimedean value group) induce an absolute value? How does one define the latter?

Comment: @Bib-lost: analysis over $p$-adifc fields would be the term. I found a clean exposition in Serre: Lie algebras and Lie groups. There are lots of references though